# Storing DDL scripts into a clob

Tags: oracle, ddl, toad

Using Toad for Oracle 10.6 with DB Admin Add-in.  For our migration process Dev to QA to Prod, we are starting to use the Schema Compare Module to generate the Sync Script DDL.  After execution, we want to store the Sync Scripts for historical purposes.  Due to policy, we are unable to copy these much of anyplace.  Even the Windows server where toad runs is write-restricted.

I am thinking I could create a table with a CLOB column and store the scripts there, unless you folks tell me that this is a Really Bad Idea.  I am looking for any tips on things like handling embedded special characters, or any other pitfalls that I may encounter.

Thanks,
JimR

Comment: Use a version control system for historical scripts. If it is impossible to do so then this sounds like a good idea; just make sure that you have the owner, table name and the creation date in your table as well as the DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the best with what you have is a good thing. If management won't let you have version control, then jamming it in the database is better than nothing at all. The important thing is to create a process, document it, and follow it for deployments.

As for using schema differences to deploy, take a look at:
http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Database-Changes-Done-Right.aspx